# iOS 7 NSLineBreakByCharWrapping wrapping at wrong characters

Tags: layout, ios7, uitableview, uilabel

I just ran into trouble with iOS 7. I want to set the `lineBreakingMode` for a `UILabel` in a `UITableViewCell` to `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping`.

My code looks like this:

```
self.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping;
self.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

In my strings special characters like ! $ & appear but I never use any kind of whitespace.

Now I recognised that iOS6 display everything correctly. The text fills the whole line and is wrapped at any character.

In iOS7 the text is wrapped at special characters (! $ &). However sometimes it looks like iOS7 breaks the lines correct.

I attached three screenshots showing the results in iOS6 and 7.

Anyone got an idea whats wrong with this?

- iOS6 (ok):
  [image]
- iOS7 (ok)
  [image]
- iOS7 (wrong)
  [image]